# 12 monthly payments with Stripe using Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I am building a system using Stripe with two plan types, both of which have a finite duration of a single year, without automatic renewal.

- Annual plan, paid once up front
- Monthly plan, paid in 12 installments (one per month).

  - The subscription period might start some time in the future, so the first payment should be collected on the start date, and each month thereafter.

I would like to use the Stripe Checkout to handle payments in both of these cases, because it gives me a lot of functionality for free.

The first case is simple, I can just create a Checkout Session with the one-off charge.

For the second case, I am having a bit of trouble.

I can create a Checkout Session with a Subscription, but it seems that a simple Subscription is not capable of modeling the finite duration of my requirements.

I can create a SubscriptionSchedule which can handle those requirements, but then I can't pass that to the Checkout.

Can anyone help me identify the best approach?

Comment: For now the approach I'm going to take is to collect payment information from the customer for the monthly plan, using the Checkout, and hope that the SubscriptionSchedule will use the attached payment for the Customer when the Schedule starts.

Comment: That's the only way I know how to do it yes. You can't create Schedules natively in Checkout, so just create one for the subscription once it's created (e.g. when handling the checkout.session.completed event).

Comment: So @karllekko you suggest creating a Subscription using Checkout, then creating the SubscriptionSchedule using `.from_subscription`, then updating the SubscriptionSchedule to meet my requirements?